# for loop using which for unique names in R

Tags: r

I have a very very large dataset, for which I am creating a fake dataset for ease. I have 4 States, 5 Years, 2 Type and Values for each. I want to get the sum of the value for each state, year and Type.

I am not getting the values I need for this if I am running the for and which loop. I was wondering if anyone knew the solution to this

```
StateName<-c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","d","d","d","d","d","d","d","d","d","d","d","d","d","d","d","d","d","d","d","d")
Year<- rep(1966:1970, times=16)
Type<-c("Y", "Y", "Y", "Y","Y","Y", "Y", "Y", "Y","Y", "Z", "Z", "Z","Z","Z","Z", "Z", "Z","Z","Z","Y", "Y", "Y", "Y","Y","Y", "Y", "Y", "Y","Y", "Z", "Z", "Z","Z","Z","Z", "Z", "Z","Z","Z","Y", "Y", "Y", "Y","Y","Y", "Y", "Y", "Y","Y", "Z", "Z", "Z","Z","Z","Z", "Z", "Z","Z","Z","Y", "Y", "Y", "Y","Y","Y", "Y", "Y", "Y","Y", "Z", "Z", "Z","Z","Z","Z", "Z", "Z","Z","Z")  
Value<-rep(1:4, times=20)
Test_Data<-cbind(StateName, Year, Type, Value)
Test_Data<-data.frame(Test_Data)

New_Table<-cbind(unique(StateName), 1966:1967, NA, NA)
New_Table<-data.frame(New_Table)
colnames(New_Table)<-c("State", "Year", "AA_Sum", "BB_Sum")


for(A in 1:nrow(Test_Data)){
  temp_index = which(as.character(Test_Data$StateName[A]) %in% as.character(New_Table$State) &
                     Test_Data$Year[A] %in% New_Table$Year &
                     Test_Data$Value[A] == "AA"  )
  New_Table$AA_Sum<- sum(Test_Data$Value[temp_index])
}
```

Currently I am getting an error "Error in Summary.factor(integer(0), na.rm = TRUE) : 
  ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors"

I was wondering if someone knew how to fill the data in New_Table with the sums of Y for each state and year, and similarly, sum for Z for each state and year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Richard correctly pointed out, you can solve this much easier with either `plyr` or `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
Test_Data %>% group_by(StateName, Year) %>% summarise(AA_Sum=sum(Value)
```

The error you are getting is due to Test_Data$Value is *a factor*. Why? Your proceedings of making the data.frame:

```
Test_Data<-cbind(StateName, Year, Type, Value)
```

binds the four vectors *into a matrix*. All columns/rows of a matrix have the same data type. Since you are binding with a character, the result is a character vector. Observe:

```
> str(cbind(StateName, Year, Type, Value))
 chr [1:4, 1:4] "a" "b" "c" "d" "1966" "1967" "1966" "1967" NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

When you convert it to a data.frame, its default behaviour is to convert character vectors into factors. It sucks. Use the argument `stringsAsFactor=FALSE` to avoid this behaviour. (Also, check the function `str`, it's really helpful for investigating an object.)

You could instead get the expected result with a single line:

```
Test_Data <- data.frame(StateName=StateName, Year=rep(1966:1970, times=16), Type=Type, Value=rep(1:4, times=20))
```

---

Lastly, your for loop will do no such thing of what you expect. a) `tempindex` will *at most* return the integer `1`, but mostly just a zero-length vector, hence the `integer(0)` part of the error. b) You are looping over all rows in `Test_Data`, but trying to summarise over the occurences found in `New_Table`. Your last line of the loop, `New_Table$AA_Sum<- ...` will simply *overwrite* the entire column with the current summation.

What you might want to be doing is (if you ignore the other answers):

```
for (i in 1:nrow(New_Table)) {
  tempindex <- which(Test_Data$StateName == New_Table$StateName[i] & ...)
  New_Table$AA_Sum[i] <- sum(Test_Data$Value[tempindex])
}
```

I've excluded some of the code for your exercise. Examine the values of `tempindex` at each `i`, and expand the expression as needed.

Comment: Thanks you so much for this information. I realised my error from your last point on incorrect looping. I will definitely take into account `plyr` too.